# Test for Trigger fails but gives 100% coverage

Tags: apex, failing-tests

So I currently just finished writing my test for a trigger that restricts a new or updated contact last name to be "INVALIDNAME". My test keeps failing during the upsert stage and i'm not sure how to approach the solution.

Heres the code:

```java
trigger RestrictContactByName on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    //check contacts prior to insert or update for invalid data
    For (Contact c : Trigger.New) {
        if(c.LastName == 'INVALIDNAME') {   //invalidname is invalid
            c.AddError('The Last Name "'+c.LastName+'" is not allowed for DML');
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my List:

```java
@isTest
private class TestRestrictContactByName{
    @isTest static void TestLastNameInvalidName(){
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'INVALIDNAME');
        upsert c;
        Test.startTest();
        Database.UpsertResult result = Database.upsert(c,false);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(!result.isSuccess());
        System.assert(result.getErrors().size()>0);
        System.assertEquals('The Last Name INVALIDNAME is not allowed for DML',result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Testing != code coverage`. They are just checked for at the same time by running test code.  You can make a test pass with zero code coverage, and (as you have discovered) you can have every line of your code touched by test methods and have a test fail.

Answer (score 0):

The test fails because of this line `upsert c;` as the exception from the DML is not caught up ,`try catch block`, but the trigger has all the conditions valid so its showing 100% coverage.

You are already making use of `Database.UpsertResult result = Database.upsert(c,false);` which will properly catch your exceptions thrown from trigger and return it.

So just remove `upsert c;` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The addError method throws an exception, to test it you should encapsulate your upsert call in a try-catch block and check if the exception message returned is the same as the one you set or not.

```
@isTest
private class TestRestrictContactByName{
    @isTest static void TestLastNameInvalidName(){
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'INVALIDNAME');
        Test.startTest();
        try{
          upsert c;
        }catch(DMLException ex){
          System.AssertEquals(ex.getMessage().contains('The Last Name INVALID is not allowed for DML'), true);
        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```